# Handling jsonp errors

Tags: jquery, ajax, youtube, jsonp

I have a code to **check Youtube video total time and get the duration using jQuery ajax**.

The code doesn't seem to catch the errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
// get Video Total Time
var youTubeURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+ video_code +'?v=2&alt=json';

$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': youTubeURL,
    'dataType': "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    error: function (xhr, testStatus, error) {
        console.log('error: '+'$.ajax() error');
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var duration = data.entry.media$group.yt$duration.seconds;
        console.log('total time: '+duration);
    }                       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You do string concatenation properly in the `success:` function, but have a typo in the `error:` function.

```
// get Video Total Time
var youTubeURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+ video_code +'?v=2&alt=json';

$.ajax({
    'global': false,
    'url': youTubeURL,
    'dataType': "jsonp",
    error: function (xhr, testStatus, error) {
        console.log('error: '+ error);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var duration = data.entry.media$group.yt$duration.seconds;
        console.log('total time: '+ duration);
    }                       
});
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the error logs. I get error 404s and 403s but don't see the error function firing.

Comment: If I'm reading the [jquery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) right, `Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests.`

Comment: Hi. I can't really understand what you mean but this example fires the error handler. http://jsfiddle.net/SrQqP/31/

Comment: @SonnyG - updated the answer to remove your `'async': false,` line. Do you need this to be synchronous? According to the documentation, `Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.`

Comment: Ok. I read the ajax documentation and ethorn10 is right. JasonP error handler does not support cross-domain script and cross-domain jsonp requests. Basically this code will never work. Is there another way to check YT video duration?

Comment: the updated code will get the duration in the success function just fine. your only problem is now handling the 400 returned from the youtube API since it won't hit the error function.

Comment: Thanks ethorn10. You are correct the error function will not be called because youtube is a cross-domain request. Is there any other way to have this code working? I need to add some code when there is an error. I tried using CORS but can't get the code to work.